# AWS Glue job arguments error: Error parsing parameter '--arguments': Expected: ',', received: '-' for input:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am creating a glue job using the cloud shell and get an error "Error parsing parameter '--arguments': Expected: ',', received: '-' for input:"

Please note that I have already created the job with default arguments (did not give any values in the default as I am passing the same while running the job)

My code is as below:

```
aws glue start-job-run --job-name <name of the job> --arguments="
--paramater1=values
--parameter2=values
<so on and so forth>
"
```

The single/ double quotes given in the arguments are fine

Request your help on this.

Thank you.